# R code clinical trials

Tags: r, bayesian

This is my code for running a clinical trial in order to show probability of a trial been successful. My problem is that I need to show that by introducing a second set of sample (n.2), how many samples are required to produce a value above the threshold of 90%. Any help please, I know I need to loop the code I have but am having trouble doing so.

```
calc.quant = function( n, X.1, a, b, n.2, nsim, thr, p1=0.025, p2=0.975 )
{   
  a.star = a + n
  b.star = b + n - X.1
  theta = rbeta( nsim, a.star, b.star 
  X.2 = rbinom( nsim, n.2, theta )

  theta.p1p2 = matrix( 0, nrow=nsim, ncol=2 )
  for( j in 1:nsim ) {
    theta.p1p2[j,] = qbeta( c( p1, p2 ), a.star + X.2[j], b.star + n.2 - X.2[j] )
  }

  return( theta.p1p2 )
}

n = 117
X.1 = 110
a = 1
b = 1
n.2 = 50
nsim = 1000
thr = .90

res = calc.quant( n, X.1, a, b, n.2, nsim, thr )

sum( res[,1] > thr ) / nsim
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for here. Also, this reads a bit like a homework problem.

Comment: I need to create a loop that keeps running the program until I get a high enough n.2 sample value that exceeds the threshold value and then  end the program. Also it is not a homework question, its part of a project that I am working on. I have tried using the repeat command but to no avail. I need to run the loop but increment it by one every time it fails to satisfy the condition.

Comment: Good to know. It's not really clear why you need a loop, though, because your loop is just storing information it isn't actually dynamically calculating anything. If you have inputs and a formula, then the function can just be the formula and you can use something from the `*apply` family of functions to generate outputs on a range of inputs. If your goal is to instead do something that actually runs until a threshold is reached, you might try a `while` loop OR continue using `for` but include a `break` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, been trying "while" already but still no joy, anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: I just added an (incomplete) answer with the two basic strategies I described. Do either of them seem to be what you're going for?

Answer (score 0):

[This is not a complete answer, but simply to get clarification on what the OP is going for.]

Basic strategy with a for-loop:

```
threshold <- somevalue
for(i in someseq){
    output <- somefunction(...)
    if(output > threshold)
        break
}
output
```

Basic strategy with a while-loop:

```
threshold <- somevalue
below.threshold <- TRUE
while(below.threshold){
    output <- somefunction(...)
    if(output > threshold)
        below.threshold <- FALSE
}
```